# Copy a Site Template to another SPWeb

Tags: powershell, site-template

I've got the following problem: There is a solution I didn't develop, that creates and configures a new Website. I have to change the Site Template that is used for this. So I changed the template Website and saved it as a Site Template, but the solution doesn't find the Site Template:

The template seems available on all Websites in the Site Collection except for the one SPWeb where the solution searches for it.

When I call `GetAvailableWebTemplates([System.UInt32]1031)` on the SPWeb of `http://mysitecollection/`, I get:

- all the standard templates
- the old Site Template
- my new Site Template

When I call it on the SPWeb of `http://mysitecollection/subweb/`, I get:

- only the old Site Template

**How do I copy my new Site Template to this Website?** Is there a way in the UI or via PowerShell? I tried to call `AllowAllWebTemplates()` on the Website, but to no avail ...

Comment: If it's a wsp then you could open the wsp, copy it to the new web and deploy it this can be done. Is it a wsp?

Comment: It is a wsp, but since the sandbox solutions are stored on the site collection, how should I copy the wsp to another web within the same site collection? Plus: the wsp of the old template is stored in exact this solution store, so the wsp seems to be in the correct place, only the template doesn't appear in the right web ...

Comment: The code doesn't work with a sandbox solution I feel because you would possibly have to use System.IO... File.ReadAllBytes to get the wsp and put it on the other web app. If you can run it maybe something like this: http://blogs.technet.com/b/patrick_heyde/archive/2009/08/28/how-to-extract-wsp-files-from-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: I really don't know where you going with this ... I could extract the wsp without any tool, using PowerShell ... but I don't want to: The wsp is exactly where it should be. Only the template is not in the right sub web.

Comment: Okay I misunderstood I thought you wanted to do it programmatically and that tool is a good example of how to do it. I was on the wrong train on the thought...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found out:

```
$templateTitle = "MySiteTemplate"
$srcWeb = Get-SPWeb http://mysitecollection
$destWeb = Get-SPWeb http://mysitecollection/subweb

$template = $srcWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1031) | where { $_.Title -eq $templateTitle }
$collection = New-Object 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection[Microsoft.SharePoint.SPWebTemplate]'
$collection.Add($template)

$destWeb.SetAvailableWebTemplates($collection, 1031)
$destWeb.Update()

$destWeb.Dispose()
$srcWeb.Dispose()
```

Comment: Note that this will most likely clear away the existing web templates. To fix this initially re-add the existing templates from `$destWeb` before adding `$template` (`$destWeb.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1031) | % { $colletion.Add($_) }`)